# Repeating a Matrix Multiplication with Different Blocks along its Diagonal

Tags: r

I have one large matrix containing several groups defined by a string, and want to multiply each group with a vector. I'm looking for a code that automatically searches for the group and multiplies this with a vector, and is also able to multiply itself (using the same moving blocks along the diagonal).

For example, let matrix `a` be:

```
a <- matrix(c(1:81) , nrow = 9 , byrow = TRUE)
```

and vector `b`

```
b <- c(5:14)
```

lets name the rows and columns:

```
names <- paste(rep(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc") , each = 3) , rep(c(1:3) , times = 3) , sep = "")
rownames(a) <- names
colnames(a) <- names
```

giving:

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
aaa2   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
aaa3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
bbb1   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
bbb2   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
bbb3   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
ccc1   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
ccc2   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
ccc3   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81
```

I would like to multiply the rows and columns of `a` starting with `aaa`with vector `b`, setting everything else to zero, then repeat with group `bbb` and `ccc` i.e.

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    1    2    3    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa2   10   11   12    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa3   19   20   21    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

for the first multiplication, and

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb1    0    0    0   31   32   33    0    0    0
bbb2    0    0    0   40   41   42    0    0    0
bbb3    0    0    0   49   50   51    0    0    0
ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 

     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
aaa3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
bbb3    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
ccc1    0    0    0    0    0    0   61   62   63
ccc2    0    0    0    0    0    0   70   71   72
ccc3    0    0    0    0    0    0   79   80   81
```

for the second and third, the results of which stored in a matrix or (if possible) or a vector that ignores the zeroes created by the off-blocks:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
aaa1   38    0    0
aaa2  200    0    0
aaa3  362    0    0
bbb1    0  866    0
bbb2    0 1109    0
bbb3    0 1352    0
ccc1    0    0 2234
ccc2    0    0 2558
ccc3    0    0 2882

aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 
  38  200  362  866 1109 1352 2234 2558 2882
```

In the best case scenario, I could also use the same code to multiply matrix `a` by itself using the same logic as above. Many many thanks for the help!

Comment: If  you can update your post, I can update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(Matrix)
as.vector(as.matrix(bdiag(a[1:3, 1:3], a[4:6, 4:6], a[7:9, 7:9])) %*% b[1:9])
#[1]   38  200  362  866 1109 1352 2234 2558 2882
```

---

Or making it more dynamic

```
un1 <- unique(sub("\\d+", "", colnames(a)))
lst1 <- lapply(un1, function(x) a[grep(x, row.names(a)), 
          grep(x, colnames(a))])
as.matrix(bdiag(lst1)) %*% b[1:9]
```

---

Or if we want a `matrix` as output

```
out <- as.matrix(bdiag(Map(`%*%`, lst1, split(b[1:9], as.integer(gl(9, 3, 9))))))
row.names(out) <- row.names(a)
out
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#aaa1   38    0    0
#aaa2  200    0    0
#aaa3  362    0    0
#bbb1    0  866    0
#bb2    0 1109    0
#bbb3    0 1352    0
#ccc1    0    0 2234
#ccc2    0    0 2558
#ccc3    0    0 2882
```

NOTE: Using only `base R` installed packages

Comment: @Adrian Isn't the `matrix` output your expected?

Answer (score 3):

First define a grouping vector `g` which has a unique value for each group.  Then use the formula shown which creates an n x n block diagonal matrix with elements of `a` having the same dimensions as `a` and multiplies that by an n x ng block diagonal matrix with the elements of b[1:9] where ng is the number of groups.

```
g <- gsub("\\d", "", colnames(a))  # c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "bbb", "bbb", ...)
(outer(g, g, "==") * a)  %*%  (outer(g, unique(g), "==") * b[seq_along(g)])
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
aaa1   38    0    0
aaa2  200    0    0
aaa3  362    0    0
bbb1    0  866    0
bbb2    0 1109    0
bbb3    0 1352    0
ccc1    0    0 2234
ccc2    0    0 2558
ccc3    0    0 2882
```

### Vector output

The question was unclear as to whether the final result should be the matrix shown above or should be the vector shown below but if the latter then use:

```
rowSums((outer(g, g, "==") * a) %*% diag(b[seq_along(g)]))
```

giving:

```
aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3 
  38  200  362  866 1109 1352 2234 2558 2882
```