# Repeating a Matrix Multiplication with Different Blocks of zeroes along its Diagonal

Tags: r

This is a similar question to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223523/repeating-a-matrix-multiplication-with-different-blocks-along-its-diagonal). So I have one large matrix containing several groups defined by a string, and want to multiply each group with a vector. The idea is to replace each element of one group with zero leaving everything else as it is, then multiply with the vector and repeat with the next group. Ideally, the results would be stored in a matrix.

The code should please be able to work for larger matrices (with bigger groups) and ideally should also work if `a%*%b` or `b%*%a`.

For example, we have matrix `a`

```
a <- matrix(c(1:81) , nrow = 9 , byrow = TRUE)
```

and vector `b`

```
b <- c(5:14)
```

lets name the rows and columns:

```
names <- paste(rep(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc") , each = 3) , rep(c(1:3) , times = 3) , sep = "")
rownames(a) <- names
colnames(a) <- names
```

that gives:

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
aaa2   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
aaa3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
bbb1   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
bbb2   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
bbb3   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
ccc1   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
ccc2   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
ccc3   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81
```

I would like to set all the elements of aaa to zero, and multiply this with `b`, then repeat with bbb and ccc. So the first matrix would look like:

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    0    0    0    4    5    6    7    8    9
aaa2    0    0    0   13   14   15   16   17   18
aaa3    0    0    0   22   23   24   25   26   27
bbb1   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
bbb2   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
bbb3   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
ccc1   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
ccc2   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
ccc3   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81
```

and the second and third:

```
     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
aaa2   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
aaa3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
bbb1   28   29   30    0    0    0   34   35   36
bbb2   37   38   39    0    0    0   43   44   45
bbb3   46   47   48    0    0    0   52   53   54
ccc1   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63
ccc2   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72
ccc3   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81

     aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 ccc1 ccc2 ccc3
aaa1    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
aaa2   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
aaa3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
bbb1   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36
bbb2   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45
bbb3   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54
ccc1   55   56   57   58   59   60    0    0    0
ccc2   64   65   66   67   68   69    0    0    0
ccc3   73   74   75   76   77   78    0    0    0
```

Multiplying these three matrices gives three vectors which are `cbind`ed into a matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
aaa1  427  465  465
aaa2  994 1194 1194
aaa3 1561 1923 1923
bbb1 2652 1786 2652
bbb2 3381 2272 3381
bbb3 4110 2758 4110
ccc1 4839 4839 2605
ccc2 5568 5568 3010
ccc3 6297 6297 3415
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` over `c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc")` and finding the selected columns and rows with `grep` like:

```
b <- c(5:13)

sapply(c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc"), function(tt) {
  a[grep(tt, rownames(a)), grep(tt, colnames(a))]  <- 0
  b %*% t(a) #or a %*% b
})
#       aaa  bbb  ccc
# [1,]  427  465  465
# [2,]  994 1194 1194
# [3,] 1561 1923 1923
# [4,] 2652 1786 2652
# [5,] 3381 2272 3381
# [6,] 4110 2758 4110
# [7,] 4839 4839 2605
# [8,] 5568 5568 3010
# [9,] 6297 6297 3415
```